# I want to hide and show products, but I don't know what command or codes I should use?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, button

I only have these buttons >>

```
<button name="action" value="activate" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Activate</button>
                
<button name="action" value="deactivate" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Deactivate</button>
```

```
elseif ($action=="active") {
    $sql = "update $table set status='Active',updated_at='$dtSave',updated_by='$sess_username' where id=$uid";
    execQuery($sql);
    alertNew("Status updated.", $script);
}
elseif ($action=="inactive") {
    $sql = "update $table set status='Inactive',updated_at='$dtSave',updated_by='$sess_username' where id=$uid";
    execQuery($sql);
    alertNew("Status updated.", $script);
}
```

What function or command should I add? I am a beginner so I have no idea how can I hide or show (controlled by admin in backend) products in frontend,

Comment: Sorry it's very unclear what you're asking, or what the context is. Please read [ask] and try again. Remember we can't see your screen, look at your specification or read your mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To send a request from the client side to the server side, you can use AJAX. Start by adding the same class for each button and creating a jQuery code for the event:

```
$('.ClassName').click(function() {
  var actionType = $(this).val();
  var dataSend = 'hideProduct=' + actionType;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'createAPage.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: dataSend,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Create a PHP file to receive the POST method:

```
if(isset($_POST['hideProduct'])) {
  $action = $_POST['hideProduct'];

  if ($action == "active") {
    $sql = "update $table set status='Active',updated_at='$dtSave',updated_by='$sess_username' where id=$uid";
  } elseif ($action == "inactive") {
    $sql = "update $table set status='Inactive',updated_at='$dtSave',updated_by='$sess_username' where id=$uid";
  }

  if(execQuery($sql)) {
    echo 'done';
  } else {
    echo 'error';
  }
}
```

Make sure to add the jQuery AJAX CDN to your project. Also, don't use an alert event after PHP executes because it won't work with AJAX. Instead, echo something and check the update status in the success method of jQuery.